# Cordova Whitelist - URL 404 error

Tags: cordova, http-status-code-404, whitelist

Attempting to access a URL to fetch data in a Cordova app but receiving a 404 error.  The log displays URL blocked by whitelist: http://urlhere.

I've installed the whitelist plugin, added  in the /platforms/android/config.xml file, and         http://urlhere; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> in the html file.

Running in Android Studio 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin allows us to implement whitelist policy for app's navigation.When we create new Cordova project, the whitelist plugin is installed and implemented by default. You can open the **config.xml** file to see **allow-intent** default settings provided by Cordova.

**Navigation Whitelist**

Navigation to **file://** URLs is allowed by default.

```
<allow-navigation href = "http://example.com/*" />
```

The **asterix sign, ***, is used to allow navigation to multiple values. In above example we are allowing navigation to all sub domains of the **example.com**. The same can be applied to protocol or prefix to the host.

```
<allow-navigation href = "*://*.example.com/*" />
```

**Intent Whitelist**

There is also **allow-intent** element which is used to specify which URLs are allowed to open the system. You can see in the **config.xml** that Cordova already allowed most of the needed links for us.

**Network Request Whitelist**

When you look inside **config.xml** file, there is `<access origin="*" />` element. This element allows all network requests to our app via Cordova hooks. If you want to allow only specific requests, you can delete it from the **config.xml** and set it yourself.

The same principle is used as in previous examples.

```
<access origin = "http://example.com" />
```

This will allow all network requests from **http://example.com.**

**Content Security Policy**

You can see current security policy for your app inside **head** element in **index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" content = "default-src 
   'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 
   'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

This is default configuration. If you want to allow everything from the same origin and **example.com** you can use −

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" content = "default-src 'self' foo.com">
```

You can also allow everything, but restrict CSS and JavaScript to the same origin.

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" content = "default-src *; 
   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 
   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```